# POST request works in Postman but not in browser

Tags: node.js

I am using a form. When I am using it with GET Request it works perfectly.  When I am checking the POST request in POSTMAN it works perfectly. But same form when I am using with Post Request on browser it says CANNOT GET ERROR.

```
 <body>
      <form action="fileupload" method="POST">
         <h1>Helllooooo</h1>
         <button type="submit">Upload your files</button>
      </form>
 </body>

   app.use('/', require('./Routes/sellerRoutes'));

   const seller=require('express').Router();
   seller.post('/fileupload', (req,res)=>{

     console.log('ssssssssssssssss');
     res.render('fileupload');
    })
     module.exports=seller;
```

Comment: Please post the error stack trace.

Comment: What post data encode do you use in postman ?

Comment: @pavelbere I'm simply enter the url define the method POST  and click on SEND button. By defutlt : Params. I'm not sending any data in body. I'm simply rendering my ejs page using POST method

Comment: @KaranDutta Could you change `<form action="fileupload" method="POST">` to `<form action="/fileupload" method="POST">`

Answer (score 0):

Check out the console in the browser to see what (if any) error messages are returned. You may also want to check out the network tab to find the request and see if there is any additional error in the response.

Based on what you've described, my first guess is that you're experiencing a CORS error. Add CORS middleware (https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html) to your express server and see if that fixes the issue.